# Detectar evento Done y Finalizar del teclado en Android

Tags: java, android

Detectar cuando el usuario pulsa sobre la tecla `Done`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que intento es una vez que el usuario ha introducido los datos al pulsar `Done` se realice una validación

Pero si el usuario decide dejar de escribir y ocultar el teclado con pulsar botón atrás, pues detectar también ese evento.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

los dos eventos se pueden detectar de manera separada. Para el primer caso, debemos poner un listener que detecte la presion de botones y con el validamos el boton de done para realizar una accion. Esto se hace de la siguiente manera

```
final EditText edittext = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittext);
edittext.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            if ((event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) && (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)) {
                //aqui iria tu codigo al presionar el boton enter o done
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

para la segunda pregunta se me ocurre escuchar cuando el edittext en cuestion pierde el focus. para eso usamos el siguiente codigo

```
 EditText txtEdit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittxt);

 txtEdit.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {          
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            if (!hasFocus) {
               // code to execute when EditText loses focus
            }
        }
    });
```

mis fuentes fueron sacados de los siguientes post

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10627137/how-can-i-know-when-an-edittext-loses-focus/10627231

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5677563/listener-for-done-button-on-edittext